# Nagios Core 4.4.5 Ncpa 2.2.0 Monitor Disk Usage in Windows Machines

Tags: nagios

I'd like to achieve the following result: from nagios core 4.4.5 receive disk usage information on several windows servers using ncpa 2.2.0.
Right now I did the following thing. I configured in nagios core the nrdp. I configured in nagios core the host and the service.

```
    define service {
host_name server_name
service_description Disk Usage
check_command check_ncpa!-t 'secret_token' -P 5693 -M disk -w 80 -c 90 -u Gi
max_check_attempts 5
check_interval 5
retry_interval 1
check_period 24x7
notification_interval 60
notification_period 24x7
contacts nagiosadmin
register 1
}
```

I configured on the windows server the passive checks

```
[passive checks]
%HOSTNAME%|__HOST__ = system/agent_version
%HOSTNAME%|CPU Usage = cpu/percent --warning 60 --critical 80 --aggregate avg
%HOSTNAME%|Memory Usage = memory/virtual --warning 80 --critical 90 --units Gi
%HOSTNAME%|Process Count = processes --warning 300 --critical 400
%HOSTNAME%|Disk Usage = disk/logical/C:|/used_percent --warning 80 --critical 90 --units Gi
```

I can see the host and different services like ram usage, cpu usage, but not the disk usage. 
I get an error I don't understand
[image]

UNKNOWN: Unable to run check on node without check method. Requested 'disk' node.

Comment: my mistake, the disk check needed extra parameters. check_command check_ncpa!-t 'TOKEN' -P 5693 -M 'disk/logical/C:|' -w 80 -c 90 -u Gi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake the disk check needed extra parameters.

```
check_command check_ncpa!-t 'TOKEN' -P 5693 -M 'disk/logical/C:|' -w 80 -c 90 -u Gi
```